# Chosen Select Returns Null

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chosen jQuery Plugin Is Returning ‘Null’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349796/chosen-jquery-plugin-is-returning-null)

I am using Chosen for jQuery and the folder field is returning null, however when I look at the source of the page, the values are given.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, my code is below:

**Here is the outputted HTML:**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1300">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Back Office | Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style Sheets/styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="../chosen/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".folderselector").chosen();
  jQuery(".chosenyesno").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 3});
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery-ui-1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery-ui-1.9.1/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
<script>
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
});
</script>
<link class="theme-css" href="../Style Sheets/headermenu.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>

<script src="../Scripts/instantiatemenu.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="welcome">
    <div class="user-panel header-divider">
                                                        <div class="user-info">
                                <nobr>
                                    <a href="#" style="padding-right: 8px;">Alex Cross</a>
                                </nobr>
                            </div>

                            <div class="user-dropbox">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="procaptureli"><a href="/Members/profile.php">PROCapture Home</a></li>
                                    <li onclick="location.href='/BackOffice/Home.php?doLogout=true';" class="logout"><a href="/BackOffice/Home.php?doLogout=true">Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </div><!-- User panel end -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/header.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <!--end header-->
    <div class="content_wrapper">
      <div class="main_content">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_main">
            <div class="menu_holder">
              <h1>Control Panel</h1>
              <ul class="menu_items">
                <li class="menu-1"><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-2"><a href="Manage Leads.php" class="current">Manage Leads</a></li>
                <li class="menu-3"><a href="Manage Autoresponses.php">Manage Autoresponses</a></li>
                <li class="menu-4"><a href="My NMVT.php">My NMVT</a></li>
                <li class="menu-5"><a href="Home.php">Lead Capture Settings</a></li>
                <li class="menu-6"><a href="Upcoming Appointments.php">Appointments</a></li>
                <li class="menu-7"><a href="Home.php">Resources</a></li>
                <li class="menu-8"><a href="Home.php">Referral System</a></li>
                <li class="menu-9"><a href="Home.php">My Account</a></li>
                <li class="menu-10"><a href="Contact Support.php">Contact Support</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end sidebar-->
        <div class="content">
          <div class="content_container">
          <div class="page_container">
          <div class="content_page_header_2">
          <span>New Lead</span>
          </div>
          <form method="POST" action="/BackOffice/New Lead.php?" class="formid1" name="form">
          <input name="username_field" type="hidden" value="homesuccessgroup">
            <div class="box_container">
            <div class="View_Edit_Lead_LongBox Boxes">
            <div class="View_Lead_Header">
            <input title="Input The Full Name Of The Lead." onFocus="if(this.value=='Full Name')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'Full Name';}" name="Lead_Name" type="text" class="FullNameInput" value="Full Name" size="25">
            </div>
            <div class="View_Lead_Info_Side">
            <span>Info</span>
            <div class="BlueBox Medium_BlueBox_2">
            <div class="wrapper_text_1">
            <p class="paragraph_1">Phone: <input title="Input The Phone Number Of The Lead." onFocus="if(this.value=='Phone Number')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'Phone Number';}" name="Phone_Field" type="text" value="Phone Number"> <br/> Email: <input title="Input The Email Of The Lead." onFocus="if(this.value=='Email')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'Email';}" name="Email_Field" type="text" value="Email"></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="BlueBox Small_BlueBox">
            <p class="paragraph_2">Have You Contacted This Lead? <select class="chosenyesno" name="contacted_field">
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No" selected="selected">No</option>
            </select>
             </p>
            </div>
            <div class="BlueBox Small_BlueBox">
              <p class="paragraph_2">
              Put Lead In Folder:  <select class="folderselector" name="selectleads">
                                <option value="Alexs Folder">Alexs Folder</option>
                                <option value="Aweber Imports">Aweber Imports</option>
                                <option value="Cold Leads">Cold Leads</option>
                                <option value="Contacted">Contacted</option>
                                <option value="Contacted Once">Contacted Once</option>
                                <option value="Contacted Twice">Contacted Twice</option>
                                <option value="Family Guy">Family Guy</option>
                                <option value="GVO Imports">GVO Imports</option>
                                <option value="Hot Leads">Hot Leads</option>
                                <option value="MCA Imports">MCA Imports</option>
                                <option value="New Leads">New Leads</option>
                                <option value="Not Contacted">Not Contacted</option>
                                <option value="UPP Leads">UPP Leads</option>
                                <option value="Visited">Visited</option>
                              </select></p>
            </div>
            <div class="shorter_blue_box FooterBox"> 
            <p>This Lead Came From: <select>Big select box... etc.</select></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="View_Lead_Notes_Side">
            <span>Notes</span>
            <div class="BlueBox Large_BlueBox">
            <div class="notes_wrapper_2">
            <textarea title="Input Any Notes You Have For The Lead(Optional)" name="Notes_Field" cols="" rows="" class="notes_field_1"></textarea>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Manage_Leads_ShortBox_1 Boxes">
          <span>Create New Lead?</span>
          <div class="button_container_1">
          <div onClick="location.href='View Folder.php?Folder=';" class="no_button SpritesPage2">
          </div>
          <input name="submit_button" type="submit" class="yes_button SpritesPage2" value=" ">
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content_page_footer">
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form">
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
          <!--end content_container-->
        </div>
        <!--end content-->
      </div>
      <!--end main_content-->
    </div>
    <!--end content_wrapper-->
  </div>
  <!--end wrapper-->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p>Copyright © 2012 PROCapture LLC</p>
      <p>Privacy Policy  |  Terms And Conditions</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Heres The Form Action:**

```
$currenttime = time();

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if($_POST['Notes_Field'] != "") {
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
    if (strpos($_POST['Lead_Name'], "'") === false) {
      if (strpos($_POST['Lead_Name'], '"') === false) {
          if (strpos($_POST['Lead_Name'], '#') === false) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Leads (FullName, Email, PhoneNumber, Country, Folder, Notes, `User`, TimeAdded, Contacted) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Lead_Name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email_Field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Phone_Field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Country_Field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Folder'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Notes_Field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($currenttime, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['contacted_field'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "View Folder.php?Folder=" . $_POST['Folder'] . "";
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
          }
          else{
          header(sprintf("Location: %s", "Error102.php"));
          }
      }
      else{
          header(sprintf("Location: %s", "Error102.php"));
      }
    }
    else {
      header(sprintf("Location: %s", "Error102.php"));
      }
}
}
else {
    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
        if (strpos($_POST['Lead_Name'], "'") === false) {
          if (strpos($_POST['Lead_Name'], '"') === false) {
            if (strpos($_POST['Lead_Name'], '#') === false) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Leads (FullName, Email, PhoneNumber, Country, Folder, `User`, TimeAdded, Contacted) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Lead_Name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email_Field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Phone_Field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Country_Field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Folder'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_field'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($currenttime, "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['contacted_field'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "View Folder.php?Folder=" . $_POST['Folder'] . "";
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
            }
            else{
                header(sprintf("Location: %s", "Error102.php"));
                }
           }
           else{
           header(sprintf("Location: %s", "Error102.php"));
           }
        }
        else {
             header(sprintf("Location: %s", "Error102.php"));
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, no one was helping so I tried again..  I did update it but still no help

Comment: Do you understand how I can fix it?

Comment: `name="selectleads"` `!=` `$_POST['Folder']` ...this should be obvious.